# What are the differences between the Prince of Tennis manga and anime?

Tags: prince-of-tennis

I have only watched the whole anime series, but I'm not sure if I'm missing content.

I have read the American arc is anime only, but are there any other arcs that are different? Also are there any major plot points that deviate from the manga?